# Using a List(arraylist) in other methods(java)

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, return

so I have this java code that input stuff and puts it into an array list:

```
public void adding() { 
    boolean loop = true;
    ArrayList<Game> thegame = new ArrayList<Game>();
    while(loop) {
        Scanner agame = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("name: \n");
        String Cgame = agame.nextLine();
        Scanner qty = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("the qty: \n");
        int CQty = qty.nextInt();


        Console wertgame = new Console(Cgame,Cqty);
        thegame.add(new Game(Cgame,Cqty));

        System.out.println("continue?");
        Scanner autre = new Scanner(System.in);
        int continu = other.nextInt();
        if(continu==1) {

        }
        else if(continu==2) {
            Main.menu();
        }
    }

    return thegame; 
}
```

However,im wondering how to use the list in other methods,I tried some things like

```
public void information(List<thegame>) {  
    System.out.print(thegame);  
})
```

I want to be able to use the list in other methods and be able to display it and also modify it.Im quite a beginner in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You havent declared `thegame` as parameter. Change

```
 public void information(List<thegame>) {  
        System.out.print(thegame);

    }}
```

to

```
public void information(List<Game> thegame) {  
        System.out.print(thegame);

    }}
```